# Add class to DIV if 4th-parent hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I'm developing a website in which there are DIVs that contain text articles and images, (all those DIVs have by class `.article`).
I'm using a library that detects when an element has scrolled into viewport and animates it and in the process, it adds the class `.aos-animate` to the element.

There's a DIV inside all `.article`s with id `#divider` and class `.dv`. Such div is just a flat horizontal line with a fill color, it is there just for design, and by default it has a width of 0px.

What I would like to do, is check somehow if an `.article` has the class `.aos-animate`, and if it has it, then target the `#divider` contained inside that `.article` and add Class `.dv-expand` (which will set the width of the #divider to 100px. It's just a nice animation feature).

I tried this at first, triggered on page scroll:

```
if ($('.article').hasClass('aos-animate')) {
   $('.dv').addClass('dv-expand');
}
```

However, that applied the `.dv-expand` class to ALL `.dv`s in the document.
So, is there a way to iterate a function to scan all `.articles` and stop when it finds one that has class `.aos-animate` and THEN having that DIV selected, find its child element with id `#divide` (or class `.dv`) AND apply a class to it?

By the way, this is how an `.article` looks like in my document:

```
<!-- Article 1 -->
<div id="at-1" class="article" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"> <!-- THIS IS THE DIV TO CHECK FOR AOS-ANIMATE CLASS -->
  <div id="tx-c-g">
     <div id="c-title">
        <p id="t-1" class="title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</p>
     </div>
     <div id="c-subset">
        <div id="c-span">
            <div id="divider" class="dv"></div> <!-- THIS IS THE DIV TO addClass('dv-expand') -->
        </div>
        <div id="c-plain" class="at-padd">
            <p id="pl-1" class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Article 1 End -->
```

I have currently 10 articles per page, but they all have the same HTML, only the text content changes.

Sorry if the title wasn't specific enough, I didn't find a short way to describe this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you don't need `if` condition also, just change your code to

```
 $('.article.aos-animate .dv').addClass('dv-expand');
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it was just as simple as using such specific selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you wanna try do that code inside .each function. so that it only applies on the match element that passes the certain condition.

```
var article =  $('.article');

$(article).each(function(){
   if($(this).hassClass('aos-animate')){
     $(this).find('.dv').addClass('dv-expand');
   }else{
     //optional if you want to remove class
   }

})
```